# How to execute code based on the text in ComboBox1?

Tags: json, excel, vba

How can I execute the code below, based on the (JSON) text displayed in combobox1?

So everything in column A shows up as an option in combobox1. When in combobox1 a certain option gets selected I would like to excecute the code below based on the selected option.

For example if `"Cat": Leonardo",` gets selected in combobox1 the code below needs to be excecuted for `"Cat": Leonardo",` in column A.

```
Sub Combobox1text()      
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, i As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i, 1) = ReplaceString(arr(i, 1))
   Next i
   sh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value = arr
   
   Dim lrw As Long
   Dim rng As Range

lrw = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each rng In Range("A1:A" & lrw)
        If (InStr(1, LCase(rng), "anycombobox1text") > 0) Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1) = rng
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function ReplaceString(strVal) As String
    If Left(strVal, 8) = """""" Then
        ReplaceString = Split(strVal, ":")(0) & ": """""
    Else
        ReplaceString = Split(strVal, ":")(0) & ": """","
    End If
End Function

'![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unuRb.png)
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter where the CBX text comes from, once it's in the combobox's list it's VBA. Accordingly, you can let VBA run different VBA subs in response to what gets selected inn the CBX. You would use `Application.Run` with a procedure name based on the CBX selection. More likely, however, you will want to call the same sub or function in every case but with a different parameter. That is no problem, either. If you would show us the two procedures you want to choose between we could advise you on the best way to call them.

Comment: Hi Variatus, thanks for your response. I would like to call the same sub or function in every case but with a different parameter (determined by the choice in the CBX). I have added an function which I forgot which is also used with this sub. If you could show me how to achieve this that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you would like to replace "anycombobox1text" with whatever the value of your ComboBox is. You can do this with "UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value". You may also want to add a ComboBox1_Change sub to your code. Something like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Combobox1text
End Sub

Sub Combobox1text()      
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, i As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i, 1) = ReplaceString(arr(i, 1))
   Next i
   sh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value = arr
   
   Dim lrw As Long
   Dim rng As Range

lrw = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each rng In Range("A1:A" & lrw)
        If (InStr(1, LCase(rng), UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value) > 0) Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1) = rng
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function ReplaceString(strVal) As String
    If Left(strVal, 8) = """""" Then
        ReplaceString = Split(strVal, ":")(0) & ": """""
    Else
        ReplaceString = Split(strVal, ":")(0) & ": """","
    End If
End Function
```

Alternatively, you can pass the value as a parameter. Also, if Combobox1text is in the UserForm then you can shorten it to ComboBox1.Value.

**Edit based on comments**

The below code will remove the value of the selected XML element and trim away the spaced. If you want the spaces just remove the Trim() wrapper.

```
Sub Combobox1text()
    If InStr(ComboBox1.Value, ":") = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, i As Long
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Remove value of selected key/value pair
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        If cell.Value = ComboBox1.Value Then
            cell.Value = Trim(Mid(cell.Value, 1, InStr(cell.Value, ":")))
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Reset ComboBox1 List
    ComboBox1.List = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A10").Value
End Sub
```

[image: My mockup of your situation]

Comment: Hi @Ben Mega I tried this code and it removes everything for every attribute. If the CBX shows "Cat": Leonardo", I would like to change this to "Cat": ", just only for the attribute "Cat": Leonardo", if this can be implemented then it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has three parts.

1. How to load a the list to a combo box.
2. How to use the selection in the CBX to trigger action that depends on the selection.
3. The action to be triggered.

Unfortunately, none of the three objects is defined sufficiently, not even the combo box itself, of which we don't know whether it is in a sheet or a form. Therefore my code below must assume many things. Therefore it is offered as a demonstration of methods, not a solution to your unknown problem.

[image: This is the worksheet]

The code will load the list in column A into the combo box. When a selection is made in the CBX the selected item in the list will be highlighted yellow. Note that all of the code must be in the code module of the worksheet on which you have the ActiveX combo box.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' 309
    
    Dim Arr         As Variant
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    With ComboBox1
        .List = Arr
        Application.EnableEvents = False    ' prevent Change event from firing
        .ListIndex = 0                      ' display first item in the list
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ' 309
    
    With ComboBox1
        MarkSelection .Value
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub MarkSelection(ByVal Animal As String)
    ' 309
    
    Dim Fnd     As Range
    
    Set Fnd = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=Animal, _
                                          LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                          LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
        Fnd.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
End Sub
```

The first procedure runs when the worksheet is activated. This is the answer to the first of your three questions. If you want another list it could be prepared and loaded instead of the one I demonstrate. Instead of "Cat: Leopard" you could load either "Cat" or "Leopard". Every item in the list could be modified or imported from a faraway location.

The second procedure reacts to a change in the CBX selection. This is in answer to the second of your questions. Instead of taking the selected value and passing it to the executing sub the value could be modified. Observe that modification of "Cat: Leopard" could take place before loading the CBX or after selection, before passing the selected value.

And that takes you to the third procedure which fails to answer your third question because you really didn't give us much information to work with. The example merely demonstrates that the same procedure can produce different results depending upon the argument with which it was called.